# Given a node $x$ on a weighted graph, what algorithms are there for finding which node has the shortest path to $x$ from a given list of nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

**Question**: We are given this problem: On a weighted graph, a node $x$ and a set of nodes $L$, which of the nodes in $L$ has the shortest path to $x$?

I would like to know if this problem has a faster solution than just calculating the distance from each node to $x$ using some solution to the [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), and choosing the node with the lowest number. Furthermore, I'm wondering if this particular problem has some name and if there are known algorithms for solving the problem that has been described in the literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, we could just use Dijkstra's algorithm *(usually)* to calculate the distance from our initial node $x$ to each node $l_i \in L$. However, this would take a while, as you may imagine.

So, what we can do is create a new node $v$, and connect it only to each $l_i \in L$. **Then**, we apply Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest $x$-$v$ path. Now we just look at the node that comes before $v$ in that path, and that would be the node in $L$ that's closest to $x$.

This problem is similar to optimizing [network flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) with multiple sources and sinks. The technique for that is to create a supersink, or supersource. It's exactly what we did here, except with paths.

Comment: how is this different to my solution?

Comment: @JorgeFernández Adding a new vertex is less disruptive to a graph than collapsing an entire collection of vertices. One has to account for assigning new weights, rebuilding the collapsed portion so as to tell the user what vertex in $L$ was the closest one, and other hiccups.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is a user ? I don't see any difference between colapsing and adding, it is the same computation with the added or colapsed vertex.

Comment: @Sid You wanted to know if this problem had a particular name. See my edit. Unfortunately I don't know of anything that talks about paths specifically, but the technique is similar.

Comment: @JorgeFernández The user is the person implementing the algorithm. It's who the output goes to. Collapsing introduces unnecessary steps into the problem (like undoing the contraction). It works, but graphs tend to be large, and when implemented into a computer, efficiency matters.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm terribly sorry, I can see now the innovation in your solution clearly. The ideas are completely different.

Comment: It's more than okay. :)

Comment: @AndreyKaipov I don't see how adding $v$ helps.  If Dijkstra's algorithm starts from $x$, it will reach the closest $l_i \in L$ to $x$ before any other elements of $L$.  So each time you reach a new node in Dijkstra's algorithm, you just check if it's in $L$ (either by marking those nodes at the beginning, or by putting them in a hashtable, either of which takes $O(1)$ time to check), and if it is, that's your answer

Comment: @Andy Adding a new node to the graph and connecting it to each node in $L$ reduces the problem to just one run of Dijkstra's, rather than running through it for each node in $L$ like proposed in the OP. Depending on the graph, it might not make much of a difference, but that's what I was thinking when I wrote this answer. I agree with your solution though. It is really a straightforward application of Dijkstra's! Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyKaipov right, I was just saying that you can solve it in one run of Dijkstra's without adding any extra nodes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Applying Dijkstra's algorithm to this case is very straightforward.  If you choose $x$ as the starting node, and use a min-heap to go through the nodes in order of distance from $x$, then the first node you reach that is $\in L$ is the closest node to $x$ that is $\in L$.

```
create a min-heap and insert x with distance 0
create an empty set of visited nodes
while the heap is not empty:
  remove the node with the minimum distance from the heap (call it n)
  if n is not in the visited set:
     add it to the visited set
     for each node m connected to n:
       if m is in L:
         m is the closest node to x
         return m and terminate algorithm
       if m is not in L:
         add m to the heap with distance: n's distance + distance from n to m
if the heap becomes empty before the inner for loop returns:
  no nodes in L are reachable from x
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea that might help. Collapse the nodes in $L$ into one single node $L'$ and make the weight of node $L'v$ the weight of the lightest edge between a vertex of $L$ and $v$. Now you only need to calculate the distance between $L'$ and $x$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do you collapse the nodes into a single vertex? Also, have you previously heard about this algorithm or the problem somewhere in the literature?

Comment: delete the nodes in $L$ and add a node $L'$, the edge $L'v$ exists if there was an edge $lv$ with $l$ in $L$ int he original graph. make the weight of the edge $L'v$ the minimum weight of an edge of the form $lv$ with $l$ in $L$